Timeshift on Ubuntu 24.04 @ subvolume not present
I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on BTRFS. Installed Timeshift and it did not work because the 24.04 system was installed on / without creating BTRFS subvolumes @ and @home. (Ubuntu 22.04 installs the system inside @, not /.)
How can we make Timeshift work with the Ubuntu 24.04 install?

I'm guessing this doesn't help?

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 22.04 server installer does not create btrfs subvolumes? It seems some users did have the same issue on 22.04. If it doesn't create subvolumes, you can boot up using a live USB session and then manually create the subvolumes using the standard @ format. Of course, keep in mind that the device names and numbers in the linked example will be different than yours. If this doesn't answer your question, please reply back to let me know and I can retract my vote.

Thanks @mchid for pointing me to those. Tried both and neither solutions worked. In fact, my system was unbootable after following the second suggestion. Got stuck in grub> prompt.

I had the same problem with 24.04 and BTRFS (re no /@ or /@home
This Guide from a Kubernetes thread describes how to modify the Ubuntu 24.04 so it does have those subvolumes.
https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/general/miscellaneous/btrfs/680895-converting-a-root-btrfs-install-to-a-subvolume-install-in-4-easy-steps

Thanks to the comments, for it gave me the general idea on how to proceed, as well as this Ubuntu article on reinstalling GRUB 2. The steps below worked on my system, a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04. Edit based on your custom setup. If you have files you can't lose, backup first.

Prepare another system to boot from (e.g. a Live USB). Or attach your system storage to another computer.
Once your system storage is attached, get its device paths, both the system disk and partition.
Example HDD paths: disk: /dev/sdb, partition: /dev/sdb2
Example NVME paths: disk: /dev/nvme0n1, partition: /dev/nvme0n1p3
These paths may be known by running lsblk or fdisk -l if using the CLI, or by launching GNOME Disks if you prefer a GUI.
On the Terminal, run these commands (lines after # are comments):

sudo su

mount /dev/${partition} /mnt
cd /mnt

# If you haven't yet, edit fstab, i.e. nano /mnt/etc/fstab. The updated fstab must point
# from @ or @home subvolumes, so change the options from "defaults" to include "subvol="
# Example root: UUID=ABC… /     btrfs subvol=@     0 0
# Example home: UUID=ABC… /home btrfs subvol=@home 0 0

btrfs subvolume create @
btrfs subvolume create @home

mv home/* @home
mv !(@|@home) @

sync

# Mount /boot and /boot/efi if those came from other partitions.
# In 24.04 by default, /boot/efi is in another partition, while /boot is not.
# To confirm, check fstab, or run `ls @/boot/` and it will list several files

# If /boot is from another partition, run: mount /dev/${boot_partition} @/boot

mount /dev/${boot-efi_partition} @/boot/efi

# https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal
# Note: Insert path for system disk, not system partition. See step 2.

grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/@/boot --efi-directory=/mnt/@/boot/efi /dev/${disk}

# Before exiting, double-check that all in @/etc/fstab are in place


Exit Live USB and boot in your system.


If needed in the future, an archived version of the Ubuntu article referenced is available here.
